# Var doesnt worry after json_decode

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have been stuck of hours with this problem.
I been trying to save a `array` with `JSON` in a `MySQL` but I can't retrieve it.

I'm doing this:

```
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
mysql_query("UPDATE `mydbase` SET `arrayfield`='".json_encode($_POST['arrayvar'])."' WHERE `id` = ".$id ) or die(mysql_error());
```

And apparently, it saves it,

To get the info I run this:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT `arrayfield` FROM `mydbase` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1");
while ($wy=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$varwitharray =$wy['arrayfield'];
}
```

If I run `echo`  **`echo $varwitharray`** I get this:

```
{"1":["1","hi","all","250.00","250.00"],"2":["1","bye","me","50.00","50.00"]}
```

If I run `VAR_DUMP` **`var_dump($varwitharray)`** I get this:

```
string(79) "{"1":["1","hi","all","250.00","250.00"],"2":["1","bye","me","50.00","50.00"]}
```

But after I run the **`json_decode`**

```
$varwitharray = json_decode($varwitharray, true);
```

I get **`NULL`** doing anything

Its been saved in a `MySQL` file type `text` with a Collation `utf8_general_ci`

What I am doing wrong?

PS. I already read a lot of the other post regarding similar isues, but Non worked for me

Comment: `echo json_last_error();` what do you get?

Comment: @user574632 I get a number **4**

Comment: Isn't it good if the var doesn't _worry_?

Comment: I copy and paste the **echo** result here [jsonlint.com](http://jsonlint.com) and it says is a valid json

Comment: I just found out the problem is the line breakers...